# Updating Sheet2 as I enter new data on Sheet1

Tags: excel, formula

I have some data on Sheet1 from B2:G5480. I also have the same data on Sheet2 from B2:G5480 for separate calculations.

What I want is as I enter new rows on Sheet1 updating Sheet2 automatically.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
Make cells in sheet2 point to cells in sheet1
For example in Sheet2 cell A1 have formula =Sheet1!A1
Replicate this principle across the range B2:G5480, being sure not to overwrite formula cells
Method 2:
Make formulae in Sheet2 refer to data in Sheet1 by prefacing cell references with Sheet1! - leave all data on sheet1 in just one place.

Comment: Thank you JGFMK, your formula is good but I think I made the question a little different.

What I want is as I enter new rows on Sheet1 update Sheet2 automatically.

Thank you

Comment: Any help over here? Thank you!